# how to set WMWARE VAPP runtime lease to NEVER EXPIRE via java api

Tags: vmware, vcloud-director-rest-api

How can I set to a vapp the runtime lease to NEVER EXPIRE on deployment of the vapp?

I'm using the vmware vcloud java api

When I deploy the vapp I use this code :

```
_vapp.deploy(false, 1000000, false).waitForTask(0);
```

the second parameter affects the runtime lese, I've tried 0 or 1 but had no effect, I got an error in deployment. How can I set this to NEVER EXPIRE??

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value to 0 will result in an infinite lease *assuming* your org's lease settings allow such a lease.

Comment: Setting it to zero doesnt help...also if I use vapp.getLeaseSettingsSection(); and set leaseSection.setDeploymentLeaseInSeconds(0); it has no effect, it I set to a biger number it takse the setting bit looks like 0 is not considered